# Mixing methods into the current class' eigenclass

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm implementing a semi-duplicate Rails pipeline by refactoring an existing Ruby class, say A, which extends ActiveRecord, to have a module, say M, with common functionality, then to be mixed into two similar AR classes, now shallow wrappers.

When taking the meat of A and mincing it into M, A's instance methods simply become methods in M, and A's class methods go into a ClassMethods submodule of M, to be mixed back into A at class-level with a self.included hook of M and extend, via the well-known idiom.

However, A is not just any class -- we use some of its class methods from DelayedJob, which does not naturally understand class methods; hence we moved some of the original class methods of A into A's eigenclass, defining them as

```
class A
  ...
  def old_plain_vanilla_class_method
    ...
  end
  class << self 
    def new_eigenclassed_class_method
      ...
    end
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

The question now is, how do we represent that in M, so it mixes right back into A's eigenclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that I understand you well (more code please), but can't you do something like this:

```
module M
  def M.included(c)
    class << c.class
      def foo
        "foo"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: works if replacing c.class with c, and M.included with self.included.